# EF6/MVC 5: How to bind a list of many-to-many resolver entities to an object in a create view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, optimization, asp.net-mvc-5

I have three tables: Players, Games, and PlayerGames (the junction table). I have a working solution for creating a game with players, but I have to get the PlayerIds directly from the Request, then create as many PlayerGames as necessary, then add them to the game object.
What I have now:

The create method:

```
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,LocationId,Date")] Game game)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int[] ids = Request["PlayerId"].Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray(); // fetching the Ids from the form
            int lastGameId = !db.Games.Any() ? 0 : db.Games.ToList().Last().Id; // I calculate the next id so I can instantiate the Playergame objects
            game.PlayerGames = new List<PlayerGame>();
            foreach (int t in ids)
                game.PlayerGames.Add(new PlayerGame { GameId = lastGameId + 1, PlayerId = t });


            //Save
        }

        //Redirect
    }
```

The relevant part of the view:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PlayerGames.First().Player, "PlayerId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("PlayerId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PlayerGames.First().Player, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

I would like to use the Entity Framework better, and I feel like I am wasting a lot of its potential by having a workaround solution like this. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good to question your work and whether it could have been done better, but ultimately there is no *right way* to do this.

However, as this is falls under the .NET umbrella I would say a good place to start is with the [official tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). I like the example they've given for the many-to-many procedure you're working on and have used it my self as a starting point before, which has since been adapted into something more generic. The selected Ids should probably be kept in the view model like in the example. Let's have a look at it:

```
private void UpdateInstructorCourses(string[] selectedCourses, Instructor 

instructorToUpdate)
{
   if (selectedCourses == null)
   {
      instructorToUpdate.Courses = new List<Course>();
      return;
   }

   var selectedCoursesHS = new HashSet<string>(selectedCourses);
   var instructorCourses = new HashSet<int>
       (instructorToUpdate.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseID));
   foreach (var course in db.Courses)
   {
      if (selectedCoursesHS.Contains(course.CourseID.ToString()))
      {
         if (!instructorCourses.Contains(course.CourseID))
         {
            instructorToUpdate.Courses.Add(course);
         }
      }
      else
      {
         if (instructorCourses.Contains(course.CourseID))
         {
            instructorToUpdate.Courses.Remove(course);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In this example the instructor is the primary entity which is being updated by the view, and a checkbox list is used to populate which courses belong to this instructor. It would be quite easy to change this into a generic type method, so that you could use it for all your Entity types - that might be an improvement on what you've already got?